# Tensorflow.js Model Dimension Mismatch

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, png, autoencoder

Im New to the tensoflow.js, I have problem with creating CNN models because dimension mismatch. I have an 3d array using `tf.browser.fromPixels(image);`.

But when im trying to train my ai it won't start, and I got the message : `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense2 to have shape [6,6,4], but got array with shape [6,6,3].`

Here is full code :

```
image = new Image(32, 32);
data = tf.browser.fromPixels(image); //to get pixel array

model = tf.sequential();
encoder = tf.layers.dense({units: 4, batchInputShape:[6, 6, 3], activation: 'relu', kernelInitializer:"randomNormal", biasInitializer:"ones"});
decoder = tf.layers.dense({units: 4, activation: 'relu'});
model.add(encoder);
model.add(decoder);
model.compile({loss:'meanSquaredError', optimizer:tf.train.adam()});

async function botTraining(model, epochs = 60){ //train ai 60 epochs
    history = 
    await model.fit(data, data,{ epochs: epochs + 1,
        callbacks:{
            onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
                console.log("Epoch:" + epoch + " Loss:" + logs.loss);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is my code :

```
image = new Image(32, 32);
data = tf.browser.fromPixels(image); //to get pixel array

model = tf.sequential();
encoder = tf.layers.dense({units: 4, batchInputShape:[6, 6, 3], activation: 'relu', kernelInitializer:"randomNormal", biasInitializer:"ones"});
decoder = tf.layers.dense({units: 4, activation: 'relu'});
model.add(encoder);
model.add(decoder);
model.compile({loss:'meanSquaredError', optimizer:tf.train.adam()});

async function botTraining(model, epochs = 60){ //train ai 60 epochs
    history = 
    await model.fit(data, data,{ epochs: epochs + 1,
        callbacks:{
            onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
                console.log("Epoch:" + epoch + " Loss:" + logs.loss);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I figured out my "`bachInputSize`" is need to set same as `decoder` units

This is fixed code :

```
image = new Image(4, 4);
data = tf.browser.fromPixels(image);

model = tf.sequential();
encoder = tf.layers.dense({units: 3, batchInputShape:[null, null, 3], activation: 'relu', kernelInitializer:"randomNormal", biasInitializer:"ones"});
decoder = tf.layers.dense({units: 3, activation: 'relu'});
model.add(encoder);
model.add(decoder);
model.compile({loss:'meanSquaredError', optimizer:tf.train.adam()});

async function botTraining(model, epochs = 60){
    history = 
    await model.fit(data, data,{ epochs: epochs + 1,
        callbacks:{
            onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
                console.log("Epoch:" + epoch + " Loss:" + logs.loss);
            }
        }
    });
}
```